# How to prove the following inequality about the functions

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

we have to show that $$(1+x)\log(1+x)-x>x, \text{ for  } x>x_0>0.$$
I have taken $f(x) =(1+x)\log(1+x)-x$, and $g(x) =x$.
So now we have to show that $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)>0 \text{ for  }x>x_0>0.$

I need some hint that what we have to do after this.

Comment: What is $x_0$? Do you need to find it?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Find $h'(x)$ and use that to get the minimum of $h(x)$ on the given domain.

Note that I'm assuming that $log$ refers to the natural logarithm since in pure math, that is generally what $log$ with no subscript refers to.

Answer (score 1):

Easier without any calculation: to get $\log(1+x)>\frac{2x}{1+x},$ simply notice that for $x$ large enough, e.g.
$$\log(1+x)>3>\frac{2x}{1+x}.$$